# Server side Java application code not compiling - why?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, compiler-construction, rpc

```
package uk.ac.hw.oncrpc;
import org.acplt.oncrpc.*;
import org.acplt.oncrpc.server.*;

import uk.ac.hw.quizgame.Game;

import java.io.IOException;

public class quizServer extends quizServerStub {
    private double sum;

    public quizServer() throws OncRpcException, IOException {
        //sum = 0.0; May used quiz globals here
    }


    @Override
    public void start_1(String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String requestQuestion_1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String question = "What is the atomic number of lithium?";

        return question;
    }

    @Override
    public String checkAnswer_1(String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void quit_1(String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void help_1(String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try { 
            quizServer server = new quizServer();
            System.out.println("Quiz ready");
            server.run();
        } catch ( Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace(System.out); }
    }

}
```

For the code above, I get the following from the compiler

```
javac quizServer.java quizServer.java:2: error: package org.acplt.oncrpc does not exist import org.acplt.oncrpc.*; ^ quizServer.java:3: error: package org.acplt.oncrpc.server does not exist import org.acplt.oncrpc.server.*; ^ quizServer.java:5: error: package uk.ac.hw.quizgame does not exist import uk.ac.hw.quizgame.Game;
                        ^ quizServer.java:9: error: cannot find symbol public class quizServer extends quizServerStub {
                                ^   symbol: class quizServerStub quizServer.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        public quizServer() throws OncRpcException, IOException {
                                   ^   symbol:   class OncRpcException   location: class quizServer quizServer.java:17: error: method does not override or implement a method from a  supertype
        @Override
        ^ quizServer.java:23: error: method does not override or implement a method from a  supertype
        @Override
        ^ quizServer.java:31: error: method does not override or implement a method from a  supertype
        @Override
        ^ quizServer.java:37: error: method does not override or implement a method from a  supertype
        @Override
        ^ quizServer.java:43: error: method does not override or implement a method from a  supertype
        @Override
        ^ quizServer.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
                        server.run();
                              ^   symbol:   method run()   location: variable server of
```

type quizServer 11 errors

But I don't see why this is causing errors? I'm not getting these errors within the eclipse IDE, so why are they appearing here?

Really sorry if this is a stupid question. I very rarely use command to compile, but I have to in this case as I need one command to run my server code, and another to run my client on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
 package uk.ac.hw.quizgame does not exist import uk.ac.hw.quizgame.Game;
```

Do you have package with this name in your application? If not (or) remove relevant code (or) you need to add appropriate jars to classpath.

Comment: I've removed that (as I don't really need it) but I'm still getting errors, probably because this class I'm trying to compile extends an already existing class in the same package. How do I compile all the classes in the same package, together, like Eclipse does?